# The apk file of my project cannot be installed and I get the Instant Ran massage

Tags: android

When I run it in my phone or an emulator, it cannot be installed and the icon is not shown.
I get the **"Instant Run performed a full build and install since the installation on the device does not match local build on disk."** message.

Here is my app build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 27
buildToolsVersion "27.0.3"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.ava.book3"
    minSdkVersion 23
    targetSdkVersion 27
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.7"
    testInstrumentationRunner 
    "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"

     }
     buildTypes {
      release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}

dependencies {
implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
//noinspection GradleCompatible
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:27.1.1'
implementation 'com.github.barteksc:android-pdf-viewer:2.0.3'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:+'

compile files('libs/jtds-1.3.1.jar')
compile 'com.zarinpal:purchase:0.0.3-beta'
implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.1'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:12.0.1'
implementation 'com.daimajia.easing:library:2.0@aar'
implementation 'com.daimajia.androidanimations:library:2.3@aar'
implementation 
 'com.github.devlight.navigationtabstrip:navigationtabstrip:1.0.4'

   }
 apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Comment: buildToolsVersion "27.0.3" cant be greater than compileSdkVersion 27

Comment: thank you so much. your comment worked.